# mahout without hadoop but other MR implementation

Tags: hadoop, mahout, in-memory

Is it easy to replace hadoop with a different map-reduce implemention (say, an in-memory map-reduce implementation) in Mahout ? Are Mahout parallel ML implementations closely coupled with Hadoop and not replaceable ?

Answer (score 0):

(Name another MapReduce implementation in Java?) No, it's tightly bound to Hadoop. But, Hadoop can run locally. In-memory as in not using a disk? This is starting to sound not even distributed, so why use MapReduce? Not all of Mahout uses Hadoop. Is that really what you're after?

Comment: How is in-memory not distributed ? Just google for MPI, or in-memory distributed database.

Comment: Distributed, to me, means over many machines. In-memory, to me, means using one shared memory for all workers. That can be distributed, but that's pretty exotic. I assumed it was not the OP's meaning.